# "expected type void" - VHDL function error

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I've written a simple function which does log2 computation of any integer number and then "ceils" it to the next integer:

```
function log2ceil(intVal: integer) return natural is
    variable i        : natural;
    variable bitCount : natural;
begin

    i := (intVal - 1);
    bitCount := 0;

    while (i > 0) loop
        bitCount := bitCount + 1;
        i:=shiftRightInt(i,1);
    end loop;

    return bitCount;
end log2ceil;
```

---

```
function shiftRightInt(ValueToShift: integer; NrToShift:natural) return integer is
begin
    return to_integer(shift_right(to_unsigned(ValueToShift, 32), NrToShift));
end shiftRightInt;
```

Works, fine. The problem is with the simulation. Every time I try to simulate it with a simple function call in a test bench:

```
stim: process
begin
    wait for 10 ns;
    log2ceil(3);
    wait;
end process;
```

it gives me following error:

```
ERROR: [VRFC 10-1472] type error near log2ceil ; expected type  void
```

Why does it expect type Void? And how can I avoid getting this error?

Comment: A function call is an expression, it returns a value.  If you were to supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  someone could have duplicated the error in another tool that might produce a more expressive error report. In an ideal world you should have gotten an error message telling you log2ceil does not designate a procedure, your usage is a syntax error.  (Try assigning the return value of the function call to a variable or signal class object of type integer or a natural).

Comment: When making a minimal, complete and verifiable example, you can try to reduce the code of the function `log2ceil` as well or just use another test function.

Comment: That is a thoroughly bizarre error message from a VHDL compiler! It would make sense for a C compiler, where procedures are simulated using "void functions" so you can call functions and discard the return values. You can't do that in VHDL.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Multiple HDL front ends, a common IR (not all elements used by every HDL) and a common simulator. The problem is that the VHDL front end didn't catch the syntax error leaving it to be caught by a linking loader rule for SystemVerilog or SystemC. The lack of VHDL standard compliance could represent parser feature 'borrowing' from another HDL - assignment isn't an operator in VHDL, it's a statement. There could be more lurking issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
stim: process
begin
  wait for 10 ns;
  log2ceil(3);
  wait;
end process;
```

is describing a procedure call, but `log2ceil` is a function. Procedures have a return type of void, whereas your function returns an integer.

You need to provide a dummy variable to collect the return value:

```
stim: process
  variable dummy : natural;
begin
  wait for 10 ns;
  dummy := log2ceil(3);
  wait;
end process;
```

The error message is a bit cryptic, but correct!

Comment: Procedures have no return value. VHDL has no type void. For another example of the same error message that does not support your hypothesis see [Expecting type void for behavioral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116813/expecting-type-void-for-behavioral), caused by two `else i that should be `elsif`s. The error message has no basis in the VHDL language. void is only found in 18. VHPI access functions describing C information models which doesn't apply in the linked question or here.

Answer (score 1):

Your tool isn't giving a very helpful error message.  The problem is that you are referencing a function in `log2ceil` that has not yet been declared.  Given the order you define things, `shiftRightInt` isn't visible yet.

When I compile your code with Modelsim, I get:
`

> (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "shiftRightInt".

Edit:  After including your process I got the error @user1155120 pointed out.  In Modelsim:

> No feasible entries for subprogram "log2ceil".

As user1155120 noted, you are calling a function in a procedure context.  You need to assign the return value to something.

First, you can swap the order of declarations.  I.e.:

```
function shiftRightInt(ValueToShift: integer; NrToShift:natural) return integer is
begin
    return to_integer(shift_right(to_unsigned(ValueToShift, 32), NrToShift));
end shiftRightInt;

function log2ceil(intVal: integer) return natural is
    variable i        : natural;
    variable bitCount : natural;
begin

    i := (intVal - 1);
    bitCount := 0;

    while (i > 0) loop
        bitCount := bitCount + 1;
        i:=shiftRightInt(i,1);
    end loop;

    return bitCount;
end log2ceil;
```

The other is to define a "prototype" of `shiftRightInt`:

```
function shiftRightInt(ValueToShift: integer; NrToShift:natural) return integer;

function log2ceil(intVal: integer) return natural is
    variable i        : natural;
    variable bitCount : natural;
begin

    i := (intVal - 1);
    bitCount := 0;

    while (i > 0) loop
        bitCount := bitCount + 1;
        i:=shiftRightInt(i,1);
    end loop;

    return bitCount;
end log2ceil;

function shiftRightInt(ValueToShift: integer; NrToShift:natural) return integer is
begin
    return to_integer(shift_right(to_unsigned(ValueToShift, 32), NrToShift));
end shiftRightInt;
```

Comment: the order has nothing to do with it, but the assignment problem is obvious.

Comment: With your given example, order does matter.  I pointed out the compilation error.  Which is why @user1155120 pointed MCVE is essential.  And I did edit my answer to include the note about the assigning of the function result.